# Vector field invariant under certain diffeomorphisms

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, vector-fields

This probably should only require elementary differential geometry but somehow I can't seem to prove it.

How can I show the vector field $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is invariant under the action of $\mathrm{SO}(n)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called the "Euler vector field" and it is actually invariant under all of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$. A nice way to see this is to look at its flow which is the scaling action
$$ \phi_t(x) = e^t x.$$
It is quite clear that this flow is invariant, because linear maps commute with scalar multiplication, and this is equivalent to invariance of the generating vector field.

Comment: Thank you so much for a nice intuitive explanation!

Answer (score 3):

To complement Mike's answer in terms of the flow, one can show this directly via the vector field, call it $X := \sum_i x_i \frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}$, by considering a linear map $A \in \text{GL}(n, \mathbb{R})$ and noting

\begin{align*} 
(A_*X)_{Ax} = & A_* (X_{x}) = \sum_i x_i A_* \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \\
= & \sum_{i,j} x_i \frac{\partial (Ax)_j}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \\
= & \sum_{i,j} x_i A_{ji} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \\
= & \sum_{j} (Ax)_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \\
= & X_{Ax},
\end{align*}

Showing $A_* X = X$. Another way (practically the same as the flow observation) is to note that a curve $\gamma_x : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ representing the vector $X_x$ (meaning $\gamma_x'(0) = X_x$) is $\gamma_x (t) = (1+t)x$, so that
$$(A \circ \gamma_x)(t) = A \gamma_x (t) = (1+t)Ax = \gamma_{Ax}(t),$$
and hence
$$(A_*X)_{Ax} = (A \circ \gamma_x)'(0) =  \gamma_{Ax}'(0) = X_{Ax}.$$

Comment: @NaotoK: A bit more generally, defining $X_A = \sum a_{ij} x_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$, one gets a correspondence $A \mapsto X_A$ between matrices and linear vector fields which furthermore satisfies $U_*(X_A) = X_{UAU^{-1}}$ when $U \in \mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$. Since the matrix representing the specific linear vector field under consideration is the identity matrix, invariance boils down to the fact that the identity commutes with all other matrices. It would be better to put this into the language of Lie algebras, but hopefully this is clear.

Comment: @Mike F Would you elaborate on how this can be put into Lie algebra language?

Comment: @jawheele Also thank you for your detailed explanation!

Comment: The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})$ of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ is naturally identified with the vector space of all $n \times n$ real matrices with bracket operation given by matrix commutator. With this identification, the adjoint action of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ on $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})$ is just  $(U,A) \mapsto UAU^{-1}$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation#Examples). So it is easy to see that the part of $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})$ fixed by the adjoint action is exactly the scalar multiples of the identity.

Comment: An action of a Lie group $G$ on a manifold $M$ can be differentiated to get an "infinitesmial action", that is a Lie algebra homomorphism $\mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{X}(M)$, where $\mathfrak{g}$ is the Lie algebra of $G$ and $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ is the (infinite-dimensional) Lie algebra of vector fields on $M$ under Lie bracket. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_vector_field#Definition). You can check that this homomorphism is equivariant with respect to the adjoint action of $G$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ and the action of $G$ on $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ coming from the action of $G$ on $M$.

Comment: The map $A \mapsto X_A$ in my first comment is basically the infinitesimal form of the natural action of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (I think you should insert a minus sign to make it a homomorphism of Lie algebras instead of an antihomomorphism). All this is to say that, if $A \in \mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})$ is invariant for the adjoint action, the vector field $X_A$ is invariant for the action of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @MikeF Makes sense. Again, thank you so much!